# Windows Share: Wrong content?

Tags: cache, network-share, windows-8.1, samba4

I like it to use Linux for many things (e.g. programming), but i also need Windows many times. So i have a virtual Ubuntu and a native Window. To share data i have installed samba on Linux (Ubuntu) and i always open this share on Windows.

But now i always see the wrong content? On Linux the target directory contains many subdirectories and files, but on windows i only see two subdirectories.

If i mount the share on the Linux machine itself i can see the full content. First i thought Windows uses some cache magic, so i disabled caching:
https://bogner.sh/2014/10/how-to-disable-smb-client-side-caching/

Unfortunately this did not help. I also saw that if a stop samba on Linux with "sudo service smbd stop" i no longer can open the share on Windows. If i start samba i can connect, but i only can see the two directories.

I am able to create files on Windows in this share, but there are not shown on the Linux, so the files are not really created?!

I have absolutely no idea whats happening, but it is very hard to work for me now, so i hope there is a solution for my problem which does not end with reinstalling my Windows.

I use samba 4, Ubuntu and Windows 8.1.

Thank you very much

Best regards

Kevin

Comment: Why not user vmware host-guest file sharing? ("shared folders" in vm configuration, accesible from linux guest under /mnt/hgfs)

Comment: Sometimes i backup the vm or i also moved it to other computers in past. I have all data on the virtual machine which makes it very easy for me to move / copy everything. Windows does not contain anything imporant (except for many software products). But you are still right, this would be a solution.